# Rendering GDI components to a buffer or d3d texture

Tags: google-chrome, gdi, redirect, direct3d

I'm trying to redirect the output of a GDI application to a buffer, preferably a d3d texture but I'll settle for a system memory buffer that I can then copy to a d3d texture.
Specifically, I'm trying to get Google Chrome to render into a d3d buffer to be displayed in a d3d application.

Are there any foolproof ways to do this or am I opening the mother of all worm-cans?

Thanks,
Tim.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally all applications would draw only within WM_PAINT, draw only to their own DC, and they would also implement WM_PRINTCLIENT so you could get a "snapshot" of the apps window DC. But most apps do not do this perfectly, so getting what the app shows into a buffer may not be easy or possible.

An option is for you to patch the chrome source code, but it's a tall order.